# queries while retrieving data from list in python

Tags: python

I have a list in python which has below data . each data represent a table name

> [tablename_20211011, tablename_20201010, tablename_20211009,
> tablename_20211009, tablename_20211008]

20211011 -- this is the date when table got created
how i can fetch the table names which are  created in last 1 year python.

if crteria is 1 yr then result should be tablename_20211011,tablename_20211009, tablename_20211008,tablename_20211009

Comment: To confirm... **Do you just wish to extract the date part of each element within your list?**
Also... **Is it files for the last calendar year?** (ie... Do you just care about those over 2020)
...or... **Those within 1 year from some point in time?**

Comment: @RMills330  i want to fetch the table name which is created in last 1 year or 6 months

Comment: what is the date format year_date_month or year_month_date

Comment: @gilf0yle
date format is yyyymmdd

Comment: check the eit updated as you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!!!works!!! here you dont need to mention last year date manually it does the job automatically

```
from datetime import date
(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
d1 = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
#this gives you date of last year

[x for x in a if x[:-8]>=d1]
```

this returns the items after the given date

Comment: thanks for the response . for eg if i want to fetch the data from current date i.e 3feb2022 , then it will include 2022 and 2021  year. , then this may not work

Comment: check the edit it works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is **always** the last 8 characters of your filename that are the date (ie. `YYYYMMDD` format), you could just use:

```
files = ['tablename_20211011', 'tablename_20201010', 'tablename_20211009', 'tablename_20211009', 'tablename_20211008']

print ([x for x in files if x[-8:] >= '20210101'])
```

Simply set the date-string to the right of the `>=` symbol as needed.

If the date is not always the last 8 characters of the string, then you *may* need to use a regular expression (regex) approach to extract it.